# Interface inheritance with generic lists

Tags: c#, generics, interface, variance

I want to build a generic system of producers and consumers for a simple project.

What I have now is

```
public interface IMessage     {    }
public interface Message1 : IMessage    {    }
public interface Message2 : IMessage    {    }
public interface IConsumer<T>    {    }
public interface IProducer<T>    {    }

public class Mop1 : IConsumer<Message1>, IProducer<Message2>
{
}



class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<IConsumer<IMessage>>();
        var mop = new Mop1();
        list.Add(mop);   // Error occurs here
    }
}
```

The last line gives an error like `cannot convert from 'Mop1' to 'IConsumer<GenericPubSub.IMessage>'`

But Mop1 implements an IConsumer of an IMessage derived type. Is this some variance problem here? What is wrong about that?

Answer (score 5):

This is tricky case. You can use co/contravariance, but...

I will simplify code a little. Just to shut up the compiler you can do that:

```
public interface IMessage { }

public interface Message1 : IMessage { }


public class Mop1 : IConsumer<Message1>
{
}

public interface IConsumer<out IMessage>
{
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<IConsumer<IMessage>>();
        var mop = new Mop1();

        list.Add(mop);   // Error occurs here
    }
}
```

`out IMessage` will do the trick as suggested in another answer, but it fundamentally doesn't fix anything. Let me show, now you want to make your interface:

```
public interface IConsumer<out IMessage>
{
    object Process (IMessage m);
}
```

aaaand it will not compile. Because simply put if you say `out IMessage` it means that return types should be derived from `IMessage`, not parameter types.

So you will have it this way:

```
public interface IConsumer<in IMessage>
{
    object Process (IMessage m);
}

public class Mop1 : IConsumer<Message1>
{
    public object Process (Message1 msg)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

To make it compile and be valid. But now your `list.Add(mop);` will not work. And rightfully so, because your `Mop1` is indeed not castable to `IConsumer<IMessage>` because if it was following code would be possible:

```
list[0].Process (new Message2 ());
```

and it is not possible because Mop1 accepts only `Message1`.

So to answer the question. You can't really do anything meaningful with message dispatching and pure C# compiler features. I see where it was going, you wanted static typing with messages and stuff. Unfortunately you can't have a list of consumers that consume specific messages in generic list, you have to have abstract signatures like `bool CanProcess(IMessage); IMessage Process(IMessage);` and cast inside. You can also do it slightly better with custom attributes and reflection, but again, not purely with C# compiler.

Comment: Assuming this is how the OP was planning to implement their interfaces (which I'll admit is very likely), this is a much more useful answer to the question.

Comment: @Asad only assumption I made that `Consumer` consumes, i.e. takes in.

Comment: Our hypothetical `IConsumer<TMessage>.Consume` could use a dynamic message parameter and be a marker interface, for all you know. Like I said, there's a lot you're assuming based on an empty interface.

Comment: @Asad I agree it is possible. But still list of consumers with parameterized generic interface doesn't make much sense, because you can't really feed messages to this list in a generic fashion, you need casts or some runtime magic. Also attributes are better then maker interfaces in most cases in C#.

Comment: Attributes may be "better", but there's plenty of very popular libraries out there that reflect the assembly and find user's types based on the interfaces they implement. If I'm not very mistaken, the popular Ninject is one of these, as is the popular Caliburn framework for WPF.

Comment: @Asad yeah but those are not marker interfaces, they seek for real things, dependency injection is completely different story.

Comment: The interface exists solely to allow the type to be discovered via reflection, and does not specify any members that utilise the type parameter. How is that not a marker interface? I'm not sure what you mean by "seeking for real things", but just so I'm clear about my definition of a marker interface, it is any interface that has an empty contract, and exists solely as a "tag".

Comment: @Asad I am aware of what is marker interface, I never came across situations when I needed them when using DI.

Comment: To answer the questions: Yes, it is a marker interface and yes, I want a list of different kinds of consumers. Seems that is not possible here. All consumers should have a "Consume" function that consumes some kind of message, this is all I expect from it. There is a way to model that, I am quite sure.

Comment: @MareInfinitus there is no way to do it statically typed. Marker interface is bad idea anyway, use custom attributes. You either do a `Consume(IMessage)` signature and cast inside and use custom attribute to find appropriate consumer, or you can do `Consome(SomeMessage)` and use some reflection to call it with what you need. There is no elegant solution, I looked into that problem some time ago. I came up with solution based on custom attributes and Expressions (to avoid runtime reflection).

Comment: @Andrey I know about custom attributes. You use them to set some Type ontop of the different messages and/or consumers? But I still do not see why this *shall* be a problem.

Comment: @MareInfinitus custom attribute let you set some *object* on top of classes, methods and more, basically it is way to provide readable metadata. The problem is with typing of message. You need a way to tell your dispatcher which classes can process what and then pass messages to them.

Answer (score 4):

In case you're planning to implement a typical producer, consumer pattern with these interfaces, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27511122/1726343) first.

---

If you want an `IConsumer<TMessage>` to *also* be an `IConsumer<TMessageBase>`, where `TMessageBase` is any type that `TMessage` inherits or implements, then you need to make your generic parameter covariant. Use the `out` modifier.

```
public interface IConsumer<out T>    {    }
```

Now `IConsumer<Message1>` is assignable to `IConsumer<IMessage>`, since `Message1` implements `IMessage`.

Comment: Except that is not exactly it, although compiles. Consumer takes messages, so it should be `in` but then it won't compile. Original logic is broken.

Comment: @Andrey We'd have to look at some method signatures to figure out what should be in and out. Right now the interfaces are completely empty.

Comment: @Asad except that `IConsumer` assumes something like `Consume(IMessage)` and it will break everything.

Comment: I have temptation to downvote it because it is utterly useless fix. It will silence compiler for this particular line but it doesn't address actual problem with co/contravariance at all.

Comment: @Andrey You're presuming a lot about the OP's code that simply isn't present in the question. I'm not going to figure out what OP's business logic is based on what they named their classes. By all means, feel free to do with your votes what you see fit. The original question asked why the error was occurring, and my answer explains what the problem is.

Comment: By no means I wanted that kind of discussion here. All I wanted to give was a simple example. And yes, Comsumers will consume.